# componentDidMount lifecycle method gets called twice during initial component loading (rendered-removed-rendered)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have two components where in my componentDidMount lifecycle method I make ajax call request for getting all items from the server.

```
//Routes in primary parent component that render 2 components
    <div className="primary">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/admin/manage-regions" exact component={() => 
              <ManageRegions />} />
        <Route path="/admin/manage-practices" exact component={() => 
               <ManagePractices />} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
//First component
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('called twice');
    const { getAllRegionsAction } = this.props;
    getAllRegionsAction({ path: 'regions', filterName: 'regions' });
  }

//Second component
 componentDidMount() {
    console.log('called twice');
    const { getAllPracticesAction } = this.props;
    getAllPracticesAction({ path: 'practice', filterName: 'practices' });
  }


export default connect(
 null,
  {
    getAllRegionsAction: getAllFilters,
  },
)(MyFirstComponent);

export default connect(
 null,
  {
    getAllPracticesAction: getAllFilters,
  },
)(MySecondComponent);
```

The problem is my componentDidMount method gets called twice. Because of that I push two actions (GET_ALL_FILTERS) to my store instead of one, that's why I receive two responses from the server instead of one. It looks like: "component-is-rendered-component-is-removed-component-is-rendered" (even visually). I've checked that in componentWillUnmount method. Indeed, during initial loading the component gets rendered, then removed, then another render gets called, that's why I got two console.log in componentDidMount. After some researching similar problems here, I tried to play with routers, leave just one component and so on.. but nothing helps. componentDidMount still gets called twice.

Comment: actions must not be called inside containers itself, use state in container.. this way your container will be rendering in loop

Comment: do you mean using local component state to save data? componentDidMount still called twice

Answer (score 0):

Are the components on the same page? If yes, just make the request in their parent component. If no, you can play around the caching.

Comment: They are two separate components. They are both rendered by appropriate route. react-router-dom version: 5.0.0

Comment: Even If I totally remove one component the second one componentDidMount method still called two times

Comment: @SiarheiKamianiok it's unusual behavior. `componentDidMount` is always called once. I think the problem is in routing. Try not to create a new arrow function here `<Route path="/admin/manage-regions" exact component={() => <ManageRegions />} />`, but pass the component like `<Route path="/admin/manage-regions" exact component={ManageRegions} />`

Comment: @SiarheiKamianiok [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vj4pznjqo7) is `componentDidMount` is called once

Comment: It seems without arrow function everything is works. Unbelivable:)

Comment: @SiarheiKamianiok happy to hear it :)